# How can I test backend code of the aws-amplify in my local?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I'm making a react-native app with **amplify**.

Backend is consisted of aws lambda, api gateway, dynamodb using Amplify-cli.

so I have amplify directory like this.

```
ㄴamplify
   ㄴ.config
   ㄴ#current-cloud-backend
   ㄴbackend
     ㄴapi
     ㄴfunction
     ㄴstorage
     ㄴawscloudformation
```

and I wrote frontend code like this.

```
    import Amplify, {API} from 'aws-amplify'; 

 resources = {
    body: params
  }
  try{
     const data = await API.get({apiName}, {path}, resources);
     if(success != null) alert(success);
     console.log('data: ', data);
     return data;
  }catch(err){
      if(fail != null) alert(fail);
      console.log('error: ', err);
  }
```

It oprates very well,

But although that is not confirmed code, I have to do **amplify push** for test them

I wanna test local code(in amplify/backend) before push them.

Is there any solution you have?

Comment: What is the problem of pushing it? you can create different environments for testing, you can have one "local-test-env" just to try things out before going to more stable environments.

Comment: @danielfranca Thanks, I didn't think about that:) I'll try that. 

But I think the time to build "amplify push" is too long. is there other way to test in local? I really thanks for your comment.

Comment: You can try using mock https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/amplify-framework-local-mocking/ I never used it, so I can't say much, but it adverts as a way to test API/functions/auth, etc locally

Answer (score 5):

```
amplify mock function <function name>
```

Hope you still need it.